# Convergence of Solutions of Integral Equations with Weakly Converging Forcing Terms

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, limits-and-convergence, parabolic-pde, semigroups-of-operators

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $y\in L^\infty(\Omega \times (0,T))$ be a mild solution of the integral equation
$$
    y(\cdot,t)=S(t) y_0+\int_0^t S(t-s) \left[u(\cdot,s)y(\cdot,s) \right] \, \mathrm{d} s \quad \forall t \in[0, T] .
    $$
where $S(t)$ is the semigroup generated by the Laplacian operator $\Delta$ and $u\in L^2(\Omega \times (0,T))$ is a given function.

Given a sequence of functions $(u_n)$ that weakly converges to $u^*$, let $y_n$ and $y^*$ be the solutions of the above equation corresponding to $u_n$ and $u^*$, respectively. My question is how to establish that $\|y^n-y^*\|_{L^2(\Omega \times (0,T))}$ converges to $0$ as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: You can write $$ y_n - y^* = \int_0^t S(t-s) [ (u_n - u^*)  y^*] ~ds + \int_0^t S(t-s) [u^n (y_n - y^*)] ~ds $$ The second term you can Gronwall. The key action is happening on the first term. To convert weak convergence to strong convergence, the most typical way is to see if you are passing through some compact operator. Here you have that if $S(t)$ is the semigroup generated by the Laplacian, then $S(t)$ should be immediately compact.

Comment: I attempted to follow this approach.
However, I encountered a problem in applying the Gronwall inequality because I am unable to bound the second term by something involiving $\|y_n(s)-y^*(s)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$ due to the fact that $u^n$ is not in $L^{\infty}(\Omega \times (0,T))$.

Comment: Wouldn't you run into exactly the same problem in setting $y_n$ to be the solution with $u_n$? How was this solved previously?